# Solve $\frac{d}{da_k}\big[\sum_{k=1}^{p}{-a_k\cdot y(n-k)}\big]$

Tags: derivatives, summation

$\frac{d}{da_k}\hat{y}(n) = \frac{d}{da_k}\big[\sum_{k=1}^{p}{-a_k\cdot y(n-k)}\big]$ is a formula that is part of [this paper](https://www.dit.ie/media/electricalengineering/documents/mikelgainza/92.pdf) (p. 6, Formula (6)). It says the solution is: 
$\frac{d}{da_k}\hat{y}(n) = -y(n-k)$. 
BUT isn't the solution $\frac{d}{da_k}\hat{y}(n) = \sum_{k=1}^{p}{-y(n-k)}$ ?

Comment: What happens when you differentiate $-a_{k+1}\cdot y(n-k)$ with respect to $a_k$?

Comment: If the ak's are independent from on to the other, when you derive by one of the ak, all the other terms are 0?

Comment: @mrtaurho if I understand correctly, this would yield $-y(n-k)$

Comment: @Ismasou well, that's what I've figured, too.. But how does the paper derive its answer? I mean, the topic is Linear Prediction and this is a thing in science since many years... I don't think it could be wrong...

Comment: @Alon Yes, exactly. And since this is the given solution I would say it is right. Hence the differential is outside of the sum it should only effect one element - The one to which the $\frac{d}{da_k}$ refers to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess there is a little propblem concerning the differential operator. My guess is that the $a_k$ there refers to *one* of the indices, lets call it $k'$ with the restriction $1 \leq k' \leq p$, and so the sum becomes

$$\frac{d}{da_{k'}}\hat{y}(n)~=~\frac{d}{da_{k'}}\left[\sum_{k=1}^p -a_k\cdot y(n-k)\right]~=~\frac{d}{da_{k'}} \left[ -a_1\cdot y(n-1)-a_2\cdot y(n-2)-~\cdots - a_{k'}\cdot y(n-k')-\cdots -a_{p-1}\cdot y(n-{p-1})-a_p\cdot y(n-p)\right]$$

By differentiation of each of the sum elements with respect to $a_{k'}$ leads to

$$0 + 0 + \cdots -y(n-k') + \cdots + 0 + 0 $$

To put this all together yields to

$$\frac{d}{da_{k'}}\hat{y}(n)~=~-y(n-k')$$

The problem is that the indices of the sum and one single variable are denoted with the same letter.

Otherwise, if the differential would be part of every single sum element, your first guess would be right.

Comment: Good answer.. for everyone seeking the same advice: There is an excellent paper by Makhoul "Linear Prediction: A Tutorial Review" that does the steps a little more granular for beginners to understand.